# Question about this notation for m-forms and differential forms:

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

In many mathematics textbooks the $m$-form on $T_p \mathbb{R}^n$ is written in a compactified notation that I haven't seen before:

$$\omega = \sum_{(1 \le i_1 < \cdots < i_m \le n)}a_{i_1 \cdots i_m} dx_{i_1} \wedge dx_{i_2} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_m}$$

Which is sometimes compactified even further to

$$ \omega = \sum_{I}a_{I} dx_I \quad ,I = (i_1 , \cdots , i_m)$$

Unfortunately there is always (in every book and online source that I've seen anyways) a dearth of concrete examples for this notation. I want to check and make sure that I'm understanding the notation properly. Are these two sub-examples correct?

---

(a)

Let's look at $2$-forms in $T_p \mathbb{R}^3$:

$$\omega = a_{i_1 i_2 } dx_{i_1} \wedge dx_{i_2} + a_{i_1  i_3} dx_{i_1} \wedge dx_{i_3} + a_{i_2 i_3} dx_{i_2} \wedge dx_{i_3}$$

For readability, set $i_1 = x$, $i_2 = y$ and $i_3 = z$. Then we set our $dx_\star$ values to our familiar $dx, dy, dz$ notation, and can give our form as

$$\omega = a_{x y } dx \wedge dy + a_{xz} dx \wedge dz + a_{yz} dy \wedge dz$$

$dx, dy$ and $dz$ are the usual covectors that we are familiar with. Some $a_{ij}$ is a scalar, and the $_{ij}$ is some indexing value, similar to how we index $2$-dimensional tensors when doing tensor algebra. That is, $a_{ij}$ can vary if we change $i$ or $j$. Let's keep $dx, dy, dz$ fixed and set $a_{xy} = 5$, $a_{xz} = 7$, and $a_{yz} = 9$. Then

$$\omega = 5 dx \wedge dy + 7 dx \wedge dz + 9 dy \wedge dz$$

Or we can tweak our $a_{ij}$ values and have $a_{xy}' = 2$, $a_{xz}' = 3$, and $a_{yz}' = -13$, which gives

$$\omega' = 2 dx \wedge dy + 3 dx \wedge dz - 13 dy \wedge dz$$

In other words, the way that we generate forms is similar to how we generate vectors in linear algebra, using a basis which spans our vector space and writing any vector $v$ which is in the space as

$$ v = \sum_i a_i e_i$$

---

(b)

Differential $m$-forms behave similarly, only now instead of being limited to constants we are limited to some $C^\infty$ function that we'll denote and index as $f_I$. Our notation becomes

$$ \omega = \sum_{I}f_{I} dx_I \quad ,I = {(i_1 , \cdots , i_m)}$$

Let's keep the example similar and look at differential $2$-forms in $T_p \mathbb{R}^3$:

$$\omega = f_{x y } dx \wedge dy + f_{xz} dx \wedge dz + f_{yz} dy \wedge dz$$

Choose $f_{xy} = (x^2 + 3x + 2)$, $f_{xz} = -\sin{x}$, and $f_{yz} = \pi^x$. Then

$$\omega = (x^2 + 3x + 2) dx \wedge dy -(\sin{x}) dx \wedge dz + (\pi^x) dy \wedge dz$$

Similarly, choose  $f_{xy}' = x$, $f_{xz}' = \cos(x)$, and $f_{yz}' = 4$, then

$$\omega = (x) dx \wedge dy + (\cos x) dx \wedge dz + 4 dy \wedge dz$$

This is again similar to defining vectors in linear algebra, only replace the constants with any $C^\infty$ function:

$$ v = \sum_i f_i e_i$$

---

Would this all be correct? Incidentally, would the set of all possible $m$ forms be called the *span*, similar to the vector spaces that we focus on in linear algebra?

Comment: The set $\{dx_I\}$ is a basis for the space of k forms as long as the indices run over $i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k$.

Comment: Your $3$-forms are $2$-forms.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that mistake. I'll correct it immediately.

Comment: In your very first displayed equation, you are missing the $i_1$, $i_2$, \dots, $i_m$ subscripts on the $dx$'s. One refers to the span of particular vectors, not to the span of all possible vectors. The set of all $m$-forms is a vector space; in fact, it is a module over the ring of smooth functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin Shifrin Changed, although if anything if was my later expression that I wrote differently. The notation was given in terms of $dx_{(1, ... , m)}$ in the video I took it from (proper timestep included)

https://youtu.be/xTWh2zaXQ80list=PL22w63XsKjqzQZtDZO_9s2HEMRJnaOTX7&t=1219

Comment: That aside, are (a) and (b) legitimate, concrete examples?

Comment: Yes, they are fine. You do not need to have a nonzero term for every basis $m$-form. By the way, you might try my YouTube lectures, linked in my profile; there are lots of examples. I don't know where you're headed, but they might help.

Comment: Oh, also, your $I\in\{i_1,\dots,i_m\}$ is just plain wrong. Did that come from the video? $I$ is an element of the set of all possible m-multiindices. An individual $I$ is a particular selection of $i_1,\dots,i_m$.

Comment: Upon checking the video that particular error appears to be my bad, the video writes it as $I = (I_1, I_2, \cdots  I_m)$. Making change now. 

A potential error on my part may be stating that the functions $f_I$ need to be $C^\infty$. The video states only that they need to be differentiable, but that only implies $C^k$ for some degree $k$. I'll keep it as $C^\infty$ until someone explicitly tells me that I should change it, since I don't know necessarily whether or not I need that smoothness as part of the definition.

Comment: Smoothness is usually assumed, but you need at least $C^1$ if you’re going to take exterior derivatives.